# Git Bash commands stop working after a while ("command not found") in Pycharm

Tags: python, bash, pycharm

I'm using Pycharm Pro for a Flask project on Windows 10.

I'm using Git Bash internally to Pycharm and globally as well. My global Git Bash works totally fine, no weird "command not found".

The Git Bash terminal internal to Pycharm initially works fine when I open a new instance of the terminal, however after I run my Flask script on `localhost`, it starts throwing "command not found" for everything.

Even if I type `python` or `python3`, it says "command not found". Same for `ls`, `cd`, etc...nothing works anymore.

During that time, my global Git Bash still works totally fine. In Pycharm, if I close the faulty terminal and open a new instance, everything works fine again.

**EDIT**: It seems to happen after I `source activate` my venv environment.

Comment: Something is mangling your PATH.

Comment: @jarmod, I don't know much about PATH unfortunately, this is all very new to me, but what's weird is that venv's I've created myself (the one is this particular Pycharm Flask project was created by Pycharm) also start messing up when I open them in the Pycharm Bash terminal, and the Pycharm-created  venv works fine if I open it in my global Git Bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing python or python3 in proper way in your virtual environment and resolve all the dependencies accordingly. For installation make sure to activate your venv and run the shell as an administrator.

Comment: Is this why `ls` and `cd` also don't work, though? No Bash command works when i open a virtual environment in Pycharm, regardless of whether it was created by Pycharm or me.
Conversely, all bash commands work fine when I open the venv's (Pycharm's or mine) using my global Git Bash installation, so it's definitely something up with Pycharm

Comment: try going through this link : https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1818 

i am sure this will help!

Comment: Thank you, that did help!